# What's the purpose of dimmed-zebra?

Tags: git

`git diff` has this feature `--color-moved=dimmed-zebra` which sounds really nifty but I just don't get it. If found `zebra` to be very useful since it shows moved blocks. But `dimmed_zebra` seems completely arbitrary to me. Why are "the bordering lines of two adjacent blocks...considered interesting"? **How does this feature help me analyze the diff more effectively?** I feel like this feature would be useful if I understood its intended purpose. A concrete example might be helpful.

Here's the snippet from the manpage.

> **zebra**
>
> Blocks of moved text of at least 20 alphanumeric characters are detected greedily. The detected blocks are painted using either the color.diff.{old,new}Moved color or color.diff.{old,new}MovedAlternative. The change between the two colors indicates that a new block was detected.
>
> **dimmed-zebra**
>
> Similar to zebra, but additional dimming of uninteresting parts of moved code is performed. The bordering lines of two adjacent blocks are considered interesting, the rest is uninteresting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dimmed-zebra` mode is useful when the patch consists mostly of moved or copied code with a few lines changed in the middle of the copied code.  Take, for example, [a particular commit from Git](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f005b0f483a507d3c7b353f4753ac3fece88bc0) (this link won't show the mode, however).

The `zebra` mode shows that there are two separate moved blocks: the former and the latter, colored in purple and blue, both of which are moved later with a single line inserted between them.  Here's an example of one moved stanza:

[image: The old location of code with zebra highlighting, in blue and purple.]
[image: The new location of code with zebra highlighting, in light blue with a single added line in green.]

It's a little hard to notice the added line; it doesn't really stand out.

With `dimmed-zebra`, almost all of the moved code is grey because it's ultimately uninteresting.  The only things that are highlighted in colors are the end of the first block, the beginning of the second block (the next line), and the lines that's added in the destination.  This mode lets you focus on (a) the added line and (b) the borders of where they came from, without caring about any of the moved code.

Here's what that code looks like in `dimmed-zebra` mode.  Notice how your eye is drawn to the relevant portions only:

[image: The old code in dimmed-zebra highlighting, with most of the data in grey.]
[image: The new code in dimmed-zebra highlighting, with only the added line in green.]

So basically, this is just an optimization for human vision to make it easier to notice what really matters.

Comment: I appreciate the example, and the automatic second-order diff being applied to the detected moved content is truly very valuable, but I really need to point out that the `# more than 1 request/response pair` getting highlighted in red is a big problem for me. Why is it red? It's present in the added place as well!

Comment: Actually I have cloned the repo and played around more. This way It's easy to test ever more complex examples, which are necessary to really get to the bottom of how these work. I found that at least 4 possible colors begin to appear, and also that there is a well defined pattern for how they show up: the alternating red and blue colors seen there are the two MovedFrom zebra-colors, and their being together represents a gap from which something was removed from this MovedFrom region.

Comment: "It's a little hard to notice the added line; it doesn't really stand out." - to be fair, this is more of a problem with either the terminal palette, the program's choices of which foreground and background colors to use, or arguably the ecosystem failing to provide a reliable way for the program to know things about the palette so as to empower the program to make better choices (because that ecosystem is an accumulation of hacks upon hacks which grew without any unifying vision or standards body).

Comment: As a counter-example, take the same diff and display it through [`delta`](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) with the bold {magenta,cyan,blue,yellow} styles [remapped to a background color change](https://dandavison.github.io/delta/color-moved-support.html), and it *stands out a lot* because now it's a solid color region, one line thick, across the whole terminal (so long as you picked colors that have good contrast - my background colors are `#500000` for removed lines, `#005000` for added lines, `#400040` and `#503050` for moved-from-here, and `#004040` and `#305050` for moved-to-here).

Comment: To be clear, this is still a great answer and gets a +1 from me, I just wanted to point out that this problem is not entirely inherent to just zebra vs dimmed-zebra.

Answer (score 1):

@bk2204's answer helped me understand with a nice example and now I want to offer another answer.

**What does it mean for moved lines to be "interesting", and not dimmed?**

When you see two highlighted lines that are at the border of two removed and moved blocks of code, you should think, "These lines are not adjacent anymore; Some code was inserted here or these blocks were completely separated."

Likewise, when you see two highlighted lines that are at the border of two added and moved blocks of code, you should think, "These lines did not used to be adjacent; Some code was removed here or these blocks came from completely different places".